# Low Pass Filter in Verilog (De0 Nano)

Tags: verilog, fpga

I'm learning verilog and was wondering how to implement a low pass filter in an fpga,

I am looking for a cut off frequency of around 50Hz,
I don't know how/where to start,

Can anyone point me in the right direction to help me get started?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far?

This is a easily answered with google:

http://jason.sdsu.edu/~ashrafi/PDF/filters_FPGA.pdf
http://file.scirp.org/pdf/CS_2015021515483091.pdf